# Retrieve and create data in many to many relationship in Laravel 8

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I want to create a user through a form. In the form, I will select the user type. Accordingly, the user is created, and it will be saved in the database. I can do everything, but I don't understand how to show user role in select menu with controller and create the user. I have three separate tables. One is for the user, the other is for the role, and the other is the user role. Please help me

**User Model**

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'roles_users');
    }
}
```

**Roles Model**

```
class Role extends Model
{
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'roles_users');
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
class FormController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        $user = User::find(1);  
 
        $role_ids = [1, 2];

        $user->roles()->attach($role_ids);
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<form action="{{route('store.data')}}" method="post">
    @csrf
    <label for="">User Type</label>
    <select name="usertype"></select>
    <option value="">Select Usertype</option>
    @foreach($data as $user)
    <option value="{{$user->id}}">{{$user->name}}</option>
    @endforeach
    <label for="">Username</label>
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <button type="submit">Add User</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I think we miss the controller function that calls the view, we currently don't see what data you pass to your view :)

Comment: @RobBiermann I'm new to laravel so I don't understand how can I pass the data to view page, because there are two diffrent table for user and user roles

Comment: Please have a look at the docs(https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/views) it explains how to pass data and how to name it :)

Answer (score 0):

First your should add **role_id** in your user table, then use hasOne Relationship function.

In your User Model, add this

```
public function role()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Role');
}
```

Then, in your Role Model, add this

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'role_id');
    }
```

Then you can call function on your controller

```
$user = User::with('role')->get();
```

Don't forget to add `use App\Models\ModelName;`on your Controller in case you wanted to use some model so you can declare `Modelname::class` instead of Model path